# Question closed on Server Fault, then make here again - should I repeat the answer?

Tags: support, answers, moving-questions

I answered a [question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/989918/install-linux-dual-boot-without-a-bootable-media/989928#989928) yesterday. It appeared off topic there (probably that's true), but it was just [asked again on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1497771/install-linux-dual-boot-without-a-bootable-media), where it is probably on-topic. Should I copy that answer here?

Comment: You could, but it is not a very good answer as it doesn't explain well enough what a beginner needs to do ... with some more work it would be a much better answer.

Comment: Probably you're right, for SuperUser it may deserve a little more explaining. I felt on ServerFault that is enough to give a direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is on topic here then it makes sense to post your solution here.

I would be tempted, for cleanliness sake, to delete your answer on Sever Fault so that the question can be cleaned up by OP or the Roomba but that is your choice. At the moment your answer is blocking their question from being deleted by the original asker and the [Roomba](https://superuser.com/help/roomba) because it has upvotes. You do not *have* to delete it though, as it is not really your fault it is off topic and your rep is your rep, but the question does not really belong there.

Past that if your question is an answer and solution then feel free to bring it over.

Comment: I wonder why it wasn't just migrated here? Is it possible?

Comment: It should be able to be migrated, but a mod chose to close it outright, possibly as there is very little detail and it's  a bit vague. If it were migrated then we could close and merge the duplicate if needs be.

Comment: The original question should be migrated, the new queston closed as a duplicate to that question, and the answer improved.  The question could still be migrated, it's still technically eligible to be migrated, won't be eligible for forever though.